# SQL Grouping a Count Select With Aggregate Total

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been working on this for far too many hours now and hit the wall. Hoping an SQL guru can help  shed some light.

```
SELECT 
CATEGORY.CategoryID, CATEGORY.Category_Name, CATEGORY_SUB.CategoryID AS Expr1, 
CATEGORY_SUB.SubCategory_Name, COUNT(SELL_1.Item_SubCategory) AS Count,

(SELECT COUNT(Item_Category) AS Expr10
 FROM SELL WHERE (UserName = 'me')
 GROUP BY Item_Category) AS Expr20

FROM SELL AS SELL_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
CATEGORY ON 
SELL_1.Item_Category = CATEGORY.Category_Name 

LEFT OUTER JOIN CATEGORY_SUB ON 
CATEGORY.CategoryID = CATEGORY_SUB.CategoryID AND SELL_1.Item_SubCategory = CATEGORY_SUB.SubCategory_Name  WHERE (SELL_1.Seller_UserName = 'me') AND (SELL_1.Item_Removed IS NULL) AND (SELL_1.Item_Pause IS NULL) AND (SELL_1.Item_Expires > GETDATE())

GROUP BY CATEGORY.Category_Name, CATEGORY_SUB.SubCategory_Name, CATEGORY.CategoryID, CATEGORY_SUB.CategoryID
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

In short the table returned should how the following columns where Expr20 is a "sum" or aggregate of the total counts of CategoryName so for example.

```
CategoryID   CategoryName   Expr1   SubCategory_Name    Count Expr20
1            CatA           200     SubCatA1            1     1
1            CatA           201     SubCatA2            2     3
1            CatA           202     SubCatA3            4     7
2            CatB           301     SubCatB1            1     1
2            CatB           302     SubCatB2            4     5
3            CatC           401     SubCatC1            3     3
3            CatC           402     SubCatC2            2     5
3            CatC           403     SubCatC3            4     9
```

And So on.

My problem is no matter what I do I cannot seem to get Expr20 to work. 
It seems the problem is with MS SQL wanting the alias after the (SELECT COUNT(Item_Category) so then it throws the error because 2 columns are returned.

I'm running MS SQL 2005. Grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to see what data you are starting with.  But, assuming you have all columns except `Expr20`, you can use `outer apply` or a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*, t2.Expr20
from sell t outer apply
     (select sum(count) as Expr20
      from sell t2
      where t2.CategoryId = t.CategoryId and
            t2.expr1 <= t.expr1
     ) t2;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thanks for the response. I copied your code to replace (SELECT COUNT(Item_Category) AS Expr10
 FROM SELL WHERE (UserName = 'me')
 GROUP BY Item_Category) AS Expr20   but I seem to get an incorrect syntax error. Apparently near the keyword "FROM"...I know...not much help this SQL Management Studio at debugging...

Comment: And Sorry...Yes...I have all columns except Expr20

Answer (score 0):

Really struggled with this and in the end used maybe a more elegant solution but potentially more server intensive...I'm not sure as I'm no SQL expert...but wanted to post my solution.

```
SELECT T1.CategoryID, Expr20, etc...
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(Item_Category)
FROM SELL WHERE (UserName = 'me')
GROUP BY Item_Category) AS Expr20
) T1
JOIN
(
SELECT CATEGORY.CategoryID, CATEGORY.Category_Name, CATEGORY_SUB.CategoryID  AS Expr1, CATEGORY_SUB.SubCategory_Name, COUNT(SELL.Item_SubCategory) AS Count...etc as shown in the question) T2
ON T1.Item_Category = T2.Category_Name 
ORDER BY T1.Counted DESC
```

Worked a treat and I got the table and results I needed grouping the category names with the correct number of sum total per line.

So the trick was to make a select around the 2 selects rather than trying to join them as this just doesn't seem possible.

How this helps someone and saves them the 13 hours or hair pulling I went through last night.